# how to fetch json data from url?

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I am not able to fetch inside elements of the json data. [Here's](http://www.miamia.co.in/dummy/?json=get_recent_posts) the link for   the json data.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //after button is clicked we download the data
    $('.button').click(function(){

        //start ajax request
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.miamia.co.in/dummy/?json=get_recent_posts",
            //force to handle it as text
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {

                //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function 
                //and pass downloaded data
                var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                //now json variable contains data in json format
                //let's display a few items
  $('#results').html('Pages:'+ json.pages + '<br />postid: '+json.posts.id);//here I am not able to get the id
             }
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an error handler to see what ajax error occurs? Is button part of a form? Is click event occuring? Not much troubleshooting information given. See [ask]

Comment: `dataType: "json" ` try to use this in your ajax

Comment: y cant you make the dataType to json instead of text. And have you tried to printing json in console?

Answer (score 0):

Things to note:

1. `dataType: "JSON"`
2. Data returned is JSON, so there is no need to parse it to JSON
3. It is `data.posts[0].id` and not `data.posts.id`

The following demo works. You can examine the json content returned in `console.log` or in developer console of your browser.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //after button is clicked we download the data
  $('body').on("click", "#button", function() {

    //start ajax request
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.miamia.co.in/dummy/?json=get_recent_posts&callback=?",

      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //let's display a few items
        $('#results').html('Pages:' + data.pages + '<br />postid: ' + data.posts[0].id); //here I am not able to get the id
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results">

</div>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Get posts">
```